# differential of an integral (composition of functions)

Tags: integration

I'm sorry, despite of all the hints here I don't manage to put it together.
Given $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\int_{0}^{x}e^{(x-t)\,A}\,b(t)\,\mathrm{d}t$

As solution $b(x) + \int_{0}^{x}A\,e^{(x-t)\,A}\,b(t)\,\mathrm{d}t$ is sugged.

Apparently the chain rule applies somehow. But I don't know which functions are chained. Is it $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left[F(x)-F(0)\right]$ ? Doesn't seem right to me...

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I was terrified by the formula, but basically I just got to plug in my values:

Solution:

$\begin{align}f(x,x)\,\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}(x) - f(x,0)\,\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}(0) + \int_{0}^{x}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}f(x,t)\\[12pt]  
 = e^{0}\,b(x)\,1-e^{x\,A}\,b(0)\,0 + \int_{0}^{x}A\,e^{(x-t)\,A}\,b(t)\,\mathrm{d}t \end{align}$

Comment: $e^0$ is one.  So is $1$.

Comment: Do you mean $b(x)+ \int_{0}^{x}A\,e^{(x-t)\,A}\,b(t)\,\mathrm{d}t $?

Comment: If $b(0) \ne 0$, that would not be a solution.